# Setting a global attribute to an woocommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add a globally defined attribute to a product in WooCommerce.
What I tried was the function

```
update_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'_product_attributes',"pa_myGlobalAttribute");
```

That didn't work. So I tried, to get the attribute terms and assign them to my globalAttribute:

```
update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'pa_myGlobalAttribute',$attribute_array);
```

The attribute array I retrieved over:

```
json_decode(json_encode(get_terms("pa_myGlobalAttribute")),true);
```

That didn't work either.

For me, it is important to assign a global attribute to a product, so if a different user edits the attribute, the changes are assigned to all the products.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: which information do you want to store in this attribute ?

Comment: All the information which is defined in the global attribute. Name, value etc. It as well should not be just a copy of the attribute, as I mentioned before, it is important that if one user edits this attribute. the changes automatically apply to all products. In other words I don't want to have many copies of one attribute each assigned to one product, but one and the same attribute assigned to many products.

Comment: is this what you need http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/?